# how to store multiple listbox values in database using mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012

I want to store multiple listbox values in db using asp.net Mvc5

I have tried like this. I want to pass multiple selected fields here
please provide soultion regarding this

In Controller Part:-

```
public bool ReportToFavourites(ReportsModel model)
    {

            var NewReport = new Report
            {
                TableName=model.Tables,
                ColumnName=model.SelectedFields
            };
            bool Result = DBFunctionOBj.SaveNewReportToFavourites(NewReport);
            return Result;          
    }
```

In view Part:-

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedFields, new SelectList(new[] { "" }), new { @class = "form-control editable" })
```

Comment: You have issue while saving to DB?

Comment: yes
if i select multiple values in listbox means it is coming only one value.and 
i need to get and store multiple values in db

Comment: `SelectedFields` is a list or a single field?

Comment: SelectedFields list value

Comment: in above code ColumnName=model.SelectedFields
ColumnName getting single value

Comment: Show me your  `SelectedFields` model. `new SelectList(new[] { "" })` this is blank. How are you showing the items in list box?

Comment: public string SelectedFields { get; set; }

Comment: Change it to `public List<string> SelectedFields { get; set; }`

Comment: actually iam moving values from one listbox to another list box

Comment: yes changed as List<string> SelectedFields { get; set; }

Comment: You should get multiple items in SelecteFields now.

Comment: ok thankq..
but  storing in db like this  System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Comment: You want to save as comma separated string?

Comment: yes. please give soultion how to save as comma separated string

Comment: Check my answer. Point#1 you have already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change your `public string SelectedFields { get; set; }` to `public List<string> SelectedFields { get; set; }`
2. While saving do as below:

   ```
   var NewReport = new Report
   {
     TableName=model.Tables,
     ColumnName=string.Join(",", model.SelectedFields)
   };
   ```